# How to refer to the deceased

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-tense

In referring to a dead person, do you say, his/her name "is" or "was" David/Lisa?

It doesn't sound incorrect to me when I say "his name is David" but does when I say "his name was," given that the person is no more. So I'm curious to know the correct way to tell someone the name of someone's that's late.

Comment: The late David Smith, the full name is usually used. Not just the first name. By the way, we don't say someone who is late. We say: someone who is deceased or dead.

Comment: We refer to a deceased person in the past tense. "John had a sister who died young. Her name was Susan."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Present/past perfect when the object is a dead person](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8305/present-past-perfect-when-the-object-is-a-dead-person)

Comment: @KateBunting - PRALINE It's not pining, it's passed on. This parrot is no more. It has ceased to be. It's expired and gone to meet its maker. This is a late parrot. It's a stiff. Bereft of life, it rests in peace. If you hadn't nailed it to the perch, it would be pushing up daisies. It's rung down the curtain and joined the choir invisible. This is an ex-parrot.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - A conversation over a dead parrot is rather different from a reference to the name of a deceased person.

Comment: @KateBunting  He's not dead, he's just resting.  He's shagged out following a prolonged squawk.

Comment: @stangdon - my point exactly.